# How to update bill number column ? or arrange in sequence wise in column in sql server

Tags: sql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I work on a code, I wish to make this type of code like I delete one and more bill on SQL server database then after I arrange or update my bill number column value, for example :- bill number is (1,2,3,4,5) then I delete my same bill record or row (1,3,5) so how can I update or arrange sequence wise bill number like this (1,2,3,).

[image: see this actually I want]

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using; MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products. What are you *actually* asking here, as you don't ask anything? What have you attempted to solve said unasked question? Why isn't it working?

Comment: I'm using SQL server .................. Actually, I'm asking :----- according to my upper image available bill number is (1, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 )  so then I delete bill no 2,5,8 with all entire row data so then available bill number(1, 1, 3,4,6,7,9  ) .......so I want the update or rearrange after deleting available data by using bill number in this order:------(1, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6) so how can i do...

Comment: What's wrong with `DELETE FROM dbo.YourTable WHERE Bill_no IN (2,5,8);`? And as the for new "number", calculate that the time you retreive the data with `ROW_NUMBER`. A `VIEW` would likely be what you *really* want. Don't reuse unique identifiers; it's a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost impossible to know what you are asking

but you can order the SQL set with ORDER BY (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

or if you need a sequential integer I would propose you add something to your query like this

```
SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY bill_no) AS rowNumber
FROM YourTable
```

that should gie you a sequential integer for each row in your set.

Comment: `name` and `bill_no` need a comma between them.

Comment: Actually, I'm asking :----- according to my upper image available bill number is (1, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 )  so then I delete bill no 2,5,8 with all entire row data so then available bill number(1, 1, 3,4,6,7,9  ) .......so I want the update or rearrange after deleting available data by using bill number in this order:------(1, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6) so how can I do...